# jQuery: проблемы с суммированием данных при parseFloat

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Столкнулся с проблемой: необходимо сложить данные с плавающей запятой, взятые из всех элементов с неким классом, парсинг идет, но сумма на выходе неверна.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var total = 0;

    $('.t1').each(function() {
        total +=  parseFloat($('.t1').html());
    });

    $('.middle-t1').append(total);
});
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="t1">114.45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="t1">122.58</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="t1">118.11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="t1">110.38</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="summ-t1"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

На выходе имеем:

114.45
122.58
118.11
110.38
457.8

Последнее значение - искомая сумма, и она отличается от реальной суммы верхних четырех строк, равной 465.52

```
parseFloat($('.t1').text());
```

Дает тот же результат.

Работаю с jquery-1.8.3, но и с 1.9 разницы не было.

Сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с такой проблемой? 
Может, само решение кривовато и есть более изящные способы, которые не будут выдавать настолько дикие результаты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// ...
$('.t1').each(function() {
    total +=  parseFloat($(this).text());
});
// ...
```

Comment: @Deonis, а ларчик просто открывался, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Решение кривовато, в том плане, что у JS есть ошибка со сложением дробных чисел.

```
0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004
```

Наверное, в конце не плохо было бы toFixed использавоть

Comment: да, в полном коде так и поступал, когда заметил такие дикие значения, тут решил привести только проблемный участок